# How to implement stack with singly linked list in the given code format

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

'This code snippet has two types of insertion and deletion methods. I tried to fill the methods but i don't get the desired output. the print functions output is not as required. the output has to be 3 2 1 4 but instead i get 3 3 3 4. Please help me to solve this'

```
"""Add a couple methods to our LinkedList class,
and use that to implement a Stack.
You have 4 functions below to fill in:
insert_first, delete_first, push, and pop.
Think about this while you're implementing:
why is it easier to add an "insert_first"
function than just use "append"?"""

class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        
    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def insert_first(self, new_element):
        "Insert new element as the head of the LinkedList"
        pass

    def delete_first(self):
        "Delete the first (head) element in the LinkedList as return it"
        pass

class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self,top=None):
        self.ll = LinkedList(top)

    def push(self, new_element):
        "Push (add) a new element onto the top of the stack"
        pass

    def pop(self):
        "Pop (remove) the first element off the top of the stack and return it"
        pass
        
    
# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a Stack
stack = Stack(e1)

# Test stack functionality
stack.push(e2)
stack.push(e3)
print (stack.pop().value)
print (stack.pop().value)
print (stack.pop().value)
print (stack.pop())
stack.push(e4)
print (stack.pop().value)
```

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        
    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def insert_first(self, new_element):
        "Insert new element as the head of the LinkedList"
        self.head = new_element
        pass

    def delete_first(self):
        "Delete the first (head) element in the LinkedList as return it"
        return self.head

class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self,top=None):
        self.ll = LinkedList(top)

    def push(self, new_element):
        "Push (add) a new element onto the top of the stack"
        if self.ll.head is None:
            self.ll.insert_first(new_element)
        else:
            self.ll.head.next = new_element
            new_element.next = self.ll.head
            self.ll.head = new_element
            self.ll.insert_first(new_element)
        pass

    def pop(self):
        "Pop (remove) the first element off the top of the stack and return it"
        if self.ll.head:
            deleted = self.ll.head
            self.ll.head.next = self.ll.head
            deleted.next = None
            return self.ll.delete_first()
        
    
# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a Stack
stack = Stack(e1)

# Test stack functionality
stack.push(e2)
stack.push(e3)
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop()
stack.push(e4)
print stack.pop().value
```

'This code snippet has two types of insertion and deletion methods. I tried to fill the methods but i don't get the desired output. the print functions output is not as required. the output has to be 3 2 1 4 but instead i get 3 3 3 4. Please help me to solve this'

Comment: Please realise that Python 2 is EOL. If you get assignments using Python 2 you may wonder whether you are using the right resource/course.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, it looks like the Stack never deletes the top value. It could either be your push algorithm, or another one inside it. Taking a look at 'delete_first()', it doesn't look like it actually removes it, just returns it. So you may be returning the first value (starting with '3'), but not actually removing it. Hopefully that's the only issue here. And maybe don't post what seems to be a school project on here, your teachers are usually smarter than you give em credit for.

Answer (score 0):

All the logic for inserting/deleting an element should be in the `LinkedList` class. The `Stack` class should just be a wrapper around it. The only thing it really needs to do is giving some different names to existing methods ("push" instead of "insert_first", "pop" instead of "delete_first").

So in the `Stack` class you should just have:

```
    def push(self, new_element):
        self.ll.insert_first(new_element)

    def pop(self):
        return self.ll.delete_first()
```

In the `LinkedList` class:

- Your implementation of the `delete_first` never deletes anything. It should take the first node (you did that correctly), but then rewire `self.head` to reference the *next* node.
- The implementation of `insert_first` overwrites any data that might already be in the list, by doing `self.head = new_element`. Whatever `self.head` was referring to before that assignment, is now lost. For example, if you had a list with 100 elements, and then execute this assignment, you'll end up with a list that just has that one element. Those 100 other nodes are lost. You should *prefix* the new element to the first element that is already in the list.

Here is the correction of those two methods:

```
    def insert_first(self, new_element):
        "Insert new element as the head of the LinkedList"
        new_element.next = self.head  # prefix the new element to the first node
        self.head = new_element  # ... and make it the first node
        pass

    def delete_first(self):
        "Delete the first (head) element in the LinkedList as return it"
        element = self.head  # remember what was the first element
        if element:
            self.head = element.next  # make its successor the first node
        return element
```